# PHPMailer, SMTP Failed to connect to server

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

I'm using PHPMailer.
But when i upload to my host i get the error SMTP connect() failed.

My environment
 1. Server OS:CentOS 7
 2. Web Services: XAMPP 5.6.8
 3. PHPMailer:5.2.4

this is my code:

```
<?php
    require_once('PHPMailer_old/class.phpmailer.php');
    try{
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;        // close TLS
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = "Test@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
    $mail->Password   = "Test";  // GMAIpassword

    $mail->FromName = "Test Manager";
    $mail->From = "Test@gmail.com";
    $to = "Test@hotmail.com";
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
    $mail->WordWrap   = 80;
    $body = "success!";
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Send();
    echo "Message has been sent.";
    }catch(phpmailerException $e){
        echo "Sending Failed";
        echo $e -> errorMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

Error Message In web:
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 
Sending FailedSMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Comment: change `$mail->Port = 465; ` to `$mail->Port = 25; ` and see

Comment: i get this message "SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) ",I think i should check my port 25.right?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone Help!
My Solution is uninstall XAMPP and respectively install apache, PHP, MySQL